# Webpage detecting / displaying different content for curl request - Why?

Tags: php, html, curl

I need to retrieve and parse the text of public domain books, such as those found on gutenberg.org, with PHP.

To retrieve the content of most webpages I am able to use CURL requests to retrieve the HTML exactly as I would find had I navigated to the URL in a browser.

Unfortunately on some pages, most importantly gutenberg.org pages, the websites display different content or send a redirect header.

For example, when attempting to load [this target, gutenberg.org, page](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/34175/pg34175.txt) a curl request gets redirected to [this different but logically related, gutenberg.org, page](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/34175?msg=welcome_stranger). I am successfully able to visit the target page with both cookies and javascript turned off on my browser.

**Why is the curl request being redirected while a regular browser request to the same site is not?**

Here is the code I use to retrieve the webpage:

```
$urlToScan = "http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/34175/pg34175.txt";

if(!isset($userAgent)){
  $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
}

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 15;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // return HTTP headers with response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlToScan);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($html == null){
    return false;  
} 
print $html;
```

Comment: I, too, am unable to reproduce your problem. Could you add a code snippet showing the code that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @madshvero. I've just added the code. Did you use PHP as well?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara That problem not existing in command line, atleast, is good news.

Comment: I used PHP yeah, seems like it's the user agent you set that makes it redirect. I'm not sure why, though. Without defining the user agent it does not redirect

Comment: @madshvero Could you post the code you used which successfully loaded the page?

Comment: Most recently I just used your code, but commented out the line setting `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`

Comment: @madshvero I'm amazed that it was as simple as that - and surprised the website would go to the extra effort for requests with a user agent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The hint is probably in the url: it says "welcome stranger". They are redirecting every "first" time visitor to this page. Once you have visited the page, they will not redirect you anymore.

THey don't seem to be saving a lot of stuff in your browser, but they do set a cookie with a session id. This is the most logical thing really: check if there is a session.

What you need to do is connect with curl AND a cookie. You can use your browsers cookie for this, but in case it expires, you'd be better of doing

- request the page.
- if the page is redirected, safe the cookie (you now have a session)
- request the page again with that cookie.

If all goes well, the second request will not redirect. Until the cookie / session expires, and then you start again. see [the manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) to see how to work with cookies/cookie-jars

Comment: I had considered that, but I was still able to navigate to that page *without* cookies enabled. Turns out they were tracking the referrer in the header! Still, your method is likely the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that one could navigate to the target page in a browser *without cookies or javascript*, yet not by `curl`, was due to the website tracking the referrer in the header. The page can be loaded without cookies by setting the appropriate referrer header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/34175?msg=welcome_stranger");
```

As pointed out by @madshvero, the page also be, surprisingly, loaded by simply excluding the user agent.

Comment: What an odd method :)

Comment: I now see your comment on the question: so it wasn't the user-agent afterall? or a combination?

Comment: @Nanne It was both, or either - depending on how you look at it. If you had a user-agent set, you needed to have either cookies enabled (for your solution) or the referrer set (which is why it still worked without cookies). Or, you could have avoided the trouble and simply not passed a user-agent.